# LinkSys Router and Ubuntu 16.10 Server

Tags: networking, server, 16.10, static-ip, cisco

I have been reading just about every question regarding setting a static IP address on the Ubuntu Server, Linksys Routers. I have the server correctly established in /etc/network/interfaces with:  x's represent valid addresses supplied by ISP.

```
# Primary Network Interface
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 74.221.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.xxx
gateway 74.xxx.xxx.xxx
broadcast 192.168.1.255
dns-search xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com (FQDN - Domain Name)
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The router is a Linksys EA6400 Smart WiFi

The Linksys router will only allow 192.xxx .... addresses when attempting to do port forwarding under the security tab.  There is no way to enter a 74. ...... ip address for the ubuntu server. This server needs to be seen in the outside (Internet world) with the 74.xxx ...etc IP address.

I thought about using DMZ. But then why would I need all the data about static IP in the /etc/network/interfaces file. I only have 1 network interface so I don't know how I can assign both a internal IP address and a static IP address to the same adapter. Ugh! And oh by the way.... What ever happen to good ole eth0!

The DMZ option allows for a range of incoming IP addresses (Source), but the (Destination) must be a 192.XXX.XXX.XXX address. Hence my statement about why configure the server as static.

Basically I can establish and run the server using private ip addressing scheme and modifying the hosts file on the development pc to think the FQDN is a 192.168.1.128 address . I just don't know how to let the true static IP address of 74.xxx.xxx.xxx for the server be seen behind my router. If I didn't have 6 other devices plus all the WiFi stuff running I dump the router all together and just use the Arris DG860p2. (Which I have not been able to log into even with only a laptop connected to it using user: admin and password: password.)

Once I figure out how to get this dog-gone 74.xxx ip address talking directly to the server, I have 5 domains, mail, samba, and ssh to run from it. It's a BIG Server - Lots of horsepower, memory and large bandwidth in-bound.

I have been struggling with this for a week now.

Would someone please help before I toss the whole works into the backyard!

Answer (score 4):

You've got a fundamental misunderstanding of the router's purpose in the network, and with networking in general.  The router takes a single IP address or a very small set of IP addresses and routes traffic to other subnets and networks.

That is, if your IP address is 74.221.10.25, your router gets assigned 74.221.10.25, your server gets assigned a private IP address (in the 192.168.0.0/16 range likely, but with a /24 CIDR range).  Your router, then, would be set to port-forward (this is called NAT) traffic coming in to be routed to your server.  This way, all your devices can go out over the one IP, and still communicate with the network.

If you want to route the IP address on the public area directly to the server, you have to plug the server into the data feed from the ISP - if they don't give you an IP range of addresses (like a /28 with 5 IP addresses) then you are going to have to settle for NAT, and not public IP routing/addressing to the server itself.